# event.stopPropagation() not working - Capturing still passes on function

Tags: javascript, html

First of all - I'm a noob. Sorry if this question is basic enough.
Second - I tried to search and as I can see I applied the solution as instructed in other posts.

With that being said...
I have three sets of DIVs. Each set consists on 2 Divs(one inside another). On the OUTER div there's a function that is saying to make a border if it's clicked.

To see the error:

1. Click on the word OUTER.
2. Click on the word INNER.

The code is suppose to make a border only in the outer.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Event Propagation</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">

        <!--Squares 1-->
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="outer" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
                Outer
                <div class="inner" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;margin:20px"> 
                    Inner
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <!--Squares 2-->
        <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="outer" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
                Outer
                <div class="inner" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;margin:20px"> 
                    Inner
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

         <!--Squares 3-->
         <div style="display:inline-block">
            <div class="outer" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
                Outer
                <div class="inner" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;margin:20px"> 
                    Inner
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

The JS

```
    <script>
        function onLoad(){
            
            const elOuter = document.querySelectorAll(".outer")

            elOuter.forEach(element=>{
                element.addEventListener('click', fnChangeColor,false)
            })
        }

        function fnChangeColor(e){

            e.target.style.border="1px solid black"

            if (e.stopPropagation) {
  
                e.stopPropagation()
            } else {
  
                e.cancelBubble = true
            }
        }

    </script>
```

FYI - I solved the question creating events to the children attributing the e.stopPropagation on them. That worked. But I know that's not the best approach. If I have a div with 100 divs inside, that'll be a hell on earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we have one outer div - the parent, and the inner div - the children.

So - the issue to understand here is:

target: Who triggered the event.
currentTarget: the element that has the function set in.

When clicking the inner div, you are clicking the children - but the element that has the function is the parent. So - the function should change the currentTarget (the outer div), not the target (that's the inner div that was clicked).

Just had to change

e.target.style.border="1px solid black"

with

```
e.currentTarget.style.border="1px solid black"
```

Answer (score 3):

this is because when you click on "Inner" e.target element is "Inner", not "Outer".

What you do seem to me to a try of understanding event delegation,
do it this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>xxx</title>
  <style>
    body > div { display:inline-block; }
    .outer     { height: 100px; width: 100px; background: lightgrey; }    
    .inner     { height: 50px; width: 50px;margin:20px; background: lightblue; }
    .bordering { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div> <div class="outer">  Outer <div class="inner">  Inner </div> </div> </div>
   <div> <div class="outer">  Outer <div class="inner">  Inner </div> </div> </div>
   <div> <div class="outer">  Outer <div class="inner">  Inner </div> </div> </div>
<script>
document.body.onclick= e => {
  if (!e.target.matches('.outer')) return // ignore other click events
  e.target.classList.toggle('bordering') 
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

or this way

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.outer').forEach(el=>{
  el.onclick=e=>{

    // console.log(e.target.className)
    if (!e.target.matches('.outer')) return // ignore other click events
    e.target.classList.toggle('bordering') 
  }
})
```

In your code, there is only one event used and no way for any propagation.

when the user click on a `.inner` the event append on the `.inner` element an never on the `.outer`.
it's like a bubble following it's a bottom up way, not the reverse.
when the bubble finds a target code (an avent listener), there is no more propagation and the bubble burst.

If you want to see an event propagation you have to set **2 event listeners** ( an that mean 2 bubles).

You can see that by adding a console.log(e.target.className) like here:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".outer, .inner") // => 6 event listeners
  .forEach(el=>{ el.addEventListener('click', getClick , false) })
 
var counter = 0

function getClick(e)
  {
  console.log( `${++counter} - event listener is on : ${e.currentTarget.className}
      clicked element is : ${e.target.className} `)
  }
  
cClear.onclick=_=>{ counter = 0; console.clear() }
```

```css
body > div { display:inline-block; }
.outer     { height: 100px; width: 100px; background: lightgrey; }    
.inner     { height: 50px; width: 50px;margin:20px; background: lightblue; }
```

```html
<div> <div class="outer"> Outer <div class="inner"> Inner </div> </div> </div>
<div> <div class="outer"> Outer <div class="inner"> Inner </div> </div> </div>
<div> <div class="outer"> Outer <div class="inner"> Inner </div> </div> </div>
<button id="cClear">clear console</button>
```

Comment: My function is only applying to document.querySelectorAll(".Outer"). At least that what I put in the code. Using your way I'll be listening to ALL clicks in the body, right? And comparing to see which element is it for then applying the function. Is that right?

Comment: @KajiyamaVK No, your function is not only applying to  ".Outer" elements, but also to ".inner". Yes, using my way I'll be listening to ALL clicks in the body. If  you prefer you can set 3 event listeners (as you have done) with the same code as mine inside, or put all the ".outer" in a div container. The matches method use the same css syntax to filter dom elements

Comment: Oh... Yeah... Because of the propagation, right? That's why I'm using the stopPropagation function. Ways to make it work I have. I wanna know why the propagation is not stopping.

Comment: @KajiyamaVK  I changed my answer with more explanations. Does it be useful for you ?

Comment: You used the solution and not even noticed. lol 
currentTarget. Just had to change the "target" with the currentTarget and everything worked. Didn't create nothing else.

Comment: @KajiyamaVK maybe you could consider validating my answer?